# Rails unpermitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to recieve some params within my controller, but I'm having issues when permitting them. This is my request payload:

```
{
    contacts: [{
            id: null,
            address: null,
            business: "Company",
            cellphone: "",
            city: null,
            country: null,
            email: "emaill@tes.te"
        }],
    name: "Entity1"
}
```

Inside my controller, I defined:

```
  def update_params
    params.permit(
      :name,
      contacts_attributes: [
        :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :business, :position, :telephone,
        :cellphone, :address, :city, :state, :country
      ]
    )
  end
```

But when I call the update_params method, only :name is permitted. Contacts is unpermitted. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `contacts:` instead of `contacts_attributes:`

Comment: permit it in model also

Comment: check if you using attr_accessible in your model and also strong_params in controller if so then please remove attr_accessible from model in rails 4.

Also check if you are having accept_nested_attributes_for contacts in your model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said, you are *permitting* `contacts_attributes` instead of `contacts`. Changing the `update_params` method like below should fix the problem.

```
def update_params
  params.permit(
    :name,
    contacts: [
      :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :business, :position, :telephone,
      :cellphone, :address, :city, :state, :country
    ]
  )
end
```

Answer (score -1):

First check in your model you have written `accept_nested_attributes_for :contacts` if yes then your code must work.